# Run batch file remotely as administrator using psexec in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, batch-file, cmd, psexec

I have a .bat file on the remote machine. when i run manually cmd as admin, executed psexec works correctly. But in C#, i stuck somewhere. I would like to run this .bat file as administrator in C# code. Here is my code. Could someone help me, please?

```
    public void CopyAtoBFolder()
    {
        int waitForExit = 1000 * 300;
        string localDestinationFolderPath = @"D:\Tool\";

        string call = localDestinationFolderPath + "CopyAtoBFolder.bat";
        Process process = new Process();

        process.StartInfo.FileName = this.path + @"\PsExec.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-accepteula " + localDestinationFolderPath + @" \\" + ip + " -i -u " + username + " -p " + password + " " + call;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        var ended = process.WaitForExit(waitForExit);
        if (!ended)
        {
            throw new TifPcbaException("Process timed out.");
        }
        int resultReturnCode = process.ExitCode;
        if (resultReturnCode != 0)
        {
            throw new TifPcbaException("PSExec return code " + resultReturnCode + " shows an error calling " + call + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

And here is the error.
**PSExec return code 6 shows an error calling D:\Tool\CopyAtoBFolder.bat**

Answer (score 1):

Add a app.manifest in your project and change the following line in app.manifest file:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

This would force your application to run as admin